# Rules Interface unresponsive and odd

Tags: rules, users

I am trying to set up a Rule to check if a user has added one of several states to an address field in a Profile2 profile. So I thought I'd do a Data Comparison.

1. I created a new rule called "Profile Save"
2. Added an Event from the drop down menu: "After saving a new profile"
3. Added "Entity has field"

   Parameter: *Entity*:[profile2], *Field*:field_address
4. Added AND and Add Condition,
5. chose "Data comparison"

But the Data Comparison form is all wonky. The drop down has div tags in it. The "Data Selectors" isn't active.

Do I have to already know what the Data selector should be? Or should it be available in the drop down?

(See images)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is this a known issue with Data Comparison.

[image: New Rule Overview]
[image: Add New Condition: Data to Compare]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport and should be posted in appropriate issue queue, not here. Please don't split the efforts to fix bugs. Keeping bugs in one place (their issue queues) helps people to find each other and work on them together. Splitting them across many sites makes fixing slower and less reliable.

Comment: My apologies. The reply from areynolds suggests the issue is already addressed in an bug report at drupal.org so I guess I shouldn't duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data selection interface often has jQuery Update-related issues; for the most part those should be solved by using the dev version (at the time of this answer) of jQuery Update and the current stable of Rules (7.x-2.7) as recommended by https://www.drupal.org/node/1810656#comment-9298435. That issue also has a good history of these problems.

[Another issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1276740) appears to describe your exact issue and has a patch. It sounds like that resolved the problem, so future visitors might try that as well after seeing if updating jQuery Update doesn't work.

Comment: I have Rules 7.x-2.7 and just downloaded the dev version of jQuery (7.x-2.4+5-dev), but am still getting the same behavior.

Comment: I applied the patch at #23 in the [Rules>>Issues page you linked to](https://www.drupal.org/node/1276740) and it cleared up the problem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for posting back, updated the answer to reflect the success of that patch for you.